# pole is well defined on the Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to show a pole is well defined on the Riemann surface.

Let $M$ is a Reimann surface, $f:M \rightarrow \hat{C}$ and $f(p)=\infty$. Suppose $(U,\varphi) $
and $(V, \psi)$ are two charts of M and $p \in V \cap U$. 
$f o \varphi^{-1}$ has a pole of orde $t$ at $\varphi^{-1}(p)$ and
$f o \psi^{-1}$ has a pole of orde $l$ at $\psi^{-1}(p)$.

How can we prove $t=l$?

Comment: Hint: Try to prove this claim for zeroes instead of poles.

Answer (score 0):

Both maps differ by a holomorphic map $\varphi \circ \psi^{-1}$ and the order of a zero (or pole) does not hange under a holomorphic coordinate change.

Comment: Actually I want to show the order of a pole does not change under holomorphic coordinate.